# Detect when your windows 8 app is uninstalled?

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-runtime, winjs, uninstallation

How can I tell using c# or winjs when your app that the user downloaded is being uninstalled?

Can you call home, or try to save the client by giving/redirecting them to a site with an exit poll?

Comment: Sounds like some annoying software.

Comment: @watson - a post uninstall survey is relatively common. Chrome did it (and may still) for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not supported. A key goal with the Windows Store is to make it seamless and painless for consumers to try apps. One result of this is that Store apps don't have any control over or hooks into install/uninstall processes. Bottom line is that the act of uninstall is not a time to try to exercise user engagement strategies. :)