# Windows 10 UWP app modify uninstall behavior

Tags: windows, winapi, uwp, uninstallation, uwp-xaml

We have a windows 10 UWP app currently in development phase, For testing, app is deployed using sideloading method. App is installed using [AddPackageAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br240961.aspx). App uninstall is done by right clicking the app on windows start menu. Is it possible to execute custom scripts as part of uninstallation?

Answer (score 1):

There was no way to do it. And I don't think that something is changed since Windows 8.
[Detect when your windows 8 app is uninstalled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23376311/detect-when-your-windows-8-app-is-uninstalled)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible for UWP applications and from the Windows 8 there is no changed planned as far as I know.